# RIP Jon Paul Steuer (original/first actor to play Worf's son "Alexander" on ST:TNG)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Steuer appeared as Alexander in only one TNG episode ("Reunion"), before the role was taken on by several other actors, most notably Brian Bonsall. It was, however, quite a performance and a great episode.

According to the [reports](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/star-trek-actor-jon-paul-184921714.html), Steuer died on January 1st at age 33.

[image]

Comment: Two downvotes?  Must be members of the Duras clan...

Comment: **They are *without honour***.

Comment: He also scored the most emotional touchdown in *Little Giants*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently he deeply disliked his experience on next show that he starred in (a recurring role on 'Grace Under Fire') and quit acting entirely but then went on to front a successful punk rock band called the Soda Pop Kids. He also opened a popular vegan restaurant in his home town of Portland.

> *"Jewels [Steurs] instantly understood the jerry-rigged catwalk's potential,
> landing a twirling leap four feet from the stage just as a climactic
> beat crashed home," Willamette Week contributor Jay Horton wrote in
> 2008, reviewing a Soda Pop Kids performance at a rock'n'roll fashion
> show. **"Some people, as they say, don't do fashion. Some people are
> fashion."***
>
> <sub><sup>[Portland Musician and Restaurateur Jonny P. Jewels Has Died](http://www.wweek.com/music/2018/01/02/portland-musician-and-restaurateur-jonny-p-jewels-has-died/)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's interesting (about him not enjoying his time on "Grace...")  I remember reading Brett Butler started exhibiting some bizarre behavior in the later seasons, due to the pressure of the show and a relapse into prescription med addiction.  I seem to recall a story about her hiking up her dress in front of one of the child actors.  It may have been Steurs.